# pure html code for fix button on specific area of webpage

Tags: html

i have currently started broadcasting on cam website. have fear of getting recorded so wanted to get dmca button on the webpage where cam get broadcasted. the website i use only allows html for users. so i have tried below codes.

```
<a style="display:scroll;position:fixed;top:100px;left:100px;" href="#" title="Back to Top"><img src="source to button "/></a>
```

this code is working good apart from a problem that when the webpage is scrolled down the button also comes down. this leave cam area clear.

Is there any way to fix the button to specific place?

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed;` fixes the element's position relative to the viewport. If you want to fix its position within the container you'll need to use `position: absolute;`, ensuring that the ancestor you're wishing to position it to has its own positioning (which can be set to `relative`).

Answer (score 0):

Change position to absolute:

```
<a style="display:scroll;position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;" href="#" title="Back to Top"><img src="source to button "/></a>
```

**position:absolute** will keep the element fixed in relation to the ancestor or first positioned element.

**position:fixed** will keep element in relation to the browser window/viewport. That is what keeping it moving along with the window scrolling.

You may read it in detail here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp